# How can I delete a dynamic string array that has been declared in another scope in C++?

Tags: c++, function, variables, dynamic, scope

Is there any way to delete a dynamic string array that has been declared in another scope? For example:

```
void func(int a){
    if(a==0){
        string ** str = new string * [1];
        str[0] = new string [2];
        str[1] = new string [2];
    }
    if(a==1){
        delete [] str[1];
        delete [] str[0];
        delete [] str;
    }
}
```

Also, is there any better way to do it, or to make a function which works similar to this?

Comment: A better question would be why you need an array of arrays of `string`. Or why you're not using `vector`s.

Comment: Can you try to clarify what it is you want `func` to do with `str` after it has been initialized but before it gets deleted?

Comment: In your example the `str` has been declared in the same scope

Comment: Examples like this [unique_ptr](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) comes handy; also agree, why not vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a way to do is, the question is why you want to do it. It is really silly to create a dynamic table in a scope1 and then trying to delete array from scope2 you from where you don't have access to scope1.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

In your code:

```
void func(int a){
    if(a==0){
        string ** str = new string * [1];
```

`str` is defined in this scope, so it only exists in this scope--that is, `str` is created when execution enters the scope, and destroyed when execution exits the scope.

The name of `str` is restricted to that scope as well, so outside that scope, the name has no meaning (unless there's some other declaration of the same name that happens to be in scope, of course).

```
        str[0] = new string [2];
        str[1] = new string [2];
```

Irrelevant to your question, but note that this has undefined behavior. Up above, you allocated a block of exactly *one* pointer to string, and stored its address in `str`. Here you're trying to use *two* pointers to string. You're writing beyond the end of the allocated memory, giving undefined behavior.

Also note that when `str` (itself) is destroyed, you'll lose access to the memory it points at (but that memory won't be deleted, so as it stands now, calling this with `a == 0` will lead inevitably to a memory leak.

```
    }
    if(a==1){
        delete [] str[1];
        delete [] str[0];
        delete [] str;
```

Getting back to your question: no. `str` is defined in the scope above, meaning that it has no meaning here.

If you want to manipulate `str` in both legs of the `if` statement, you can define it outside that `if` statement:

```
void func(int a){
    static string ** str;

    if(a==0){
        str = new string * [2];
        str[0] = new string [2];
        str[1] = new string [2];
    }
    if(a==1){
        delete [] str[1];
        delete [] str[0];
        delete [] str;
    }
}
```

I've made `str` static so it's preserved between calls to the function (since you apparently want to call the function once with one value to create the strings, and again with a different value to destroy them.

This still smells (stinks) of XY problem though--it's not clear what you're really trying to accomplish here, but whatever you want to do, this is almost certainly the wrong way to do it. The change I've outlined above makes the code syntactically meaningful, but the code is still much more a problem than a solution.

Comment: Well I'm a begginer and I'm trying to make a function that would read a file and get information from the file to the dynamic array, so I can later use it in the program. I wanted this to be a function so I could use it multiple times by just calling it out.

Comment: @Memust: This is really beyond the scope of what a single function should do (but it could be a class with a few member functions). I'd advise looking up `std::vector` and forgetting about `new` for the next year or two.